# SQL Developer steals focus

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I cannot find a solution to this in SQL Developer settings. I start a query in SQL Developer. Then, I start working on something else. I am writing code. Being nearly blind, I don't look at my screen. I just type until I'm done and then scan what I typed with a screenreader. Then, I try to compile it, but I get weird results until I find that 10 minutes ago, SQL Developer stole focus and I've been typing into the SQL query window, not my text editor.

Is there some way to disable SQL Developer's ability to steal focus?

I am using Linux and running SQL Developer 3.2.20.09 on OpenJDK 1.8.0_40.

Update:
I am now using SQL Developer 4.1.1.19 and I still have the same problem with  no apparent solution. Whenever a query finished in SQL Developer, it steals focus. Because SQL Developer is a Java application, I've been trying to find something in Java to block windows from stealing focus. Still, I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for some information about SQL Developer stealing focus, and I didnt found anything interesthing.

But I found that for Windows (Xp and 7):

For Win XP users:

- https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus

For Win 7 users:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-how-to-stop-application-foreground-focus/bbfc3d0d-8b20-409d-bfef-035209e1e1d4
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/applications-stealing-focus-reg-key-no-longer/4ee5be7d-31ef-493b-b092-f6f6139f99cd

Comment: Thanks. I found that. It is a registry hack to block focus requests in Windows. I use Linux, so I haven't done that. I will update my question as I should have noted the OS.